# How can I render the position of nodes in a React component tree?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a React component that acts and renders like a 2D array, where each array item is aware of its position without having to declare each item's position manually. Take these two examples:

```
const FirstExample = () => (
  <Table>
    <Column>
      <Cell>top left</Cell>
      <Cell>bottom left</Cell>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Cell>top right</Cell>
      <Cell>bottom right</Cell>
    </Column>
  </Table>
);

const SecondExample = () => {
  const columns = [
    ['top left', 'bottom left'],
    ['top right', 'bottom right']
  ];
  const RenderedColumns = () => (
    <>
      {columns.map(column => (
        <Column>
          {column.map(cell => <Cell>{cell}</Cell>)}
        </Column>
      ))}
    </>
  );
  return <Table><RenderedColumns/></Table>;
}
```

Both examples should render as:

```html
<div component="Table">
  <div component="Cell" column="0" row="0">top left</div>
  <div component="Cell" column="0" row="1">bottom left</div>
  <div component="Cell" column="1" row="0">top right</div>
  <div component="Cell" column="1" row="1">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

(Note that the Column component doesn't render a wrapping div - not that it matters a whole lot)

I included both examples because I was able to get the first one to work by iterating through the children of Table (and their children) and getting their index within the React.Children array. That approach doesn't work in the second example, because RenderedColumns is the only direct child of Table.

I've tried using context to change a counter on Table when a Column is added, and so forth, but every approach I've tried so far always ends up in an infinite loop.

It seems like a fairly simple problem to solve, but I'm completely stumped!

Answer (score -1):

Just pass column and row number to Cell props like

```
const RenderedColumns = () => (
  <>
    {columns.map((column, col) => (
      <Column>
        {column.map((cell, row) => <Cell column={col} row={row}>{cell}</Cell>)}
      </Column>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to build a React component that acts and renders like a 2D array, where each array item is aware of its position **without having to declare each item's position manually**.

Comment: Besides, this only works for the second example. I'm trying to find a solution that works for the first, the second and any other ways to build Columns and Cells.

Comment: In other words, is there a way for Cells to figure out their own position within the component tree? Or is there a way for Table to pass that information down to the Cells programmatically?